# Nodejs GET REST API and frequent access to MongoDb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, rest

I'm implementing a web app using the MERN framework (MongoDB, Express and Node.js for the back-end, React for the front-end).

In a section of my web app, I need to access a collection of the Mongo database very frequently (every 50 ms).
I need to synchronize this data with a video player.

I'd like to know which is the best way to handle this situation. 
The options I came up with right now are:

1. Send a single GET request to the collection and save the whole content of that collection in a variable of the front-end  (but I think it's the worst solution, since the size of this collection is 350MB)
2. Send a GET request every 50 ms
3. Send a GET request every N seconds based on the current time of the video player, and save the content of the request dynamically in a variable of the front-end

I'm sure there are better ways to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

i think correct approach to achieve that is to open sockets in you application as it will poll you server automatically.here is the link [socket.io](https://socket.io)